# Get Polymer Webcomponent Tester running in TeamCity CI

Tags: teamcity, polymer-1.0, web-component, web-component-tester

I need to run all my unit tests for a collection of webcomponents as a build step in my TeamCity environment (You may assume TeamCity is always up-to-date). I have no idea where to begin. Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have a suacelabs account? if so, wct has built in support for saucelabs

Answer (score 0):

In your build configuration in TeamCity, add a command line build step like below:

```
npm install
npm run bower -- install
npm test
```

your `package.json` can have the `scripts` define as:

```
"scripts": {
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "bower": "bower",
    "wct": "wct",
    "test": "gulp build && wct"
  },
```